# Aligning 3 images in HTML Email

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQzId.png)When I align 3 images in HTML email, it works in some email clients, but not in others. Any ideas what I did wrong? Want the 3 images evenly spaced across the email, centered. Here is the code I am using:

```
<div>
<img align="left" src="img link" style="float: left; width: 28%; margin-right: 8%; margin-bottom: .5em;" width="28">
<img src="img link" style="float: middle; width: 28%; margin-right: 5%; margin-bottom: .5em;" width="28">
<img align="right" src="img link" style="float: right; width: 28%; margin-right: 0%; margin-bottom: .5em;" width="28">
</div>
```

This image is how it looks in Outlook 2013 for PC. on mac they were centered and aligned 
[version on PC,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQzId.png)

Comment: Why do you use `width='25'` if you already used css styling? Also which email clients did you exactly use. Is it possible that the css gets ignored? How does it look in the clients in which it doesn't work?

Comment: float: middle ?!? It doesn't exists

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I *believe* the width thing was auto appended by the email tool im using (pardot).

Comment: Outlook 2013 for PC it did not render correctly. Iphone and outlook 2016 for mac it looked great

Answer (score 2):

Try using a table. Email clients are notoriously difficult to style for and have widely different implementations, but most end up being very similar in terms of layout if everything's in a table.

Pretty simple markup:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 33%;">
```

etc..

Comment: As much as I despise using the antiquated table layout, Adam is right. This approach has always proven consistent for me as well.

Comment: @jsloan I've updated my response. Note that some clients (I'm looking at you, outlook for web) sometimes think they can 'help' and add <td> elements to a <tr> if another row has more columns. You can prevent this behavior by making sure you're using the colspan attribute to even out the column amount.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
put in div width=100%
```

and in each image

```
width = 28%  max-width = XXXpx display=inline-block
```

Respect your code:
for your code width=28% and width=28 is wrong idea use only one, when you use (margin-right: 5%; margin-bottom: .5em;") this introduce diferent widths in diferents resolutions, use pixels in all or "em" in all.

Answer (score 0):

On my own opinion ,you can play with property ' [flex](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) '

Instead of adjusting the width of image , maybe it is better to adjust image's margin in your case , and it can keep image be centered on its block , here is a demo
http://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/jApyZz

```
<div style='display : flex;'>
   <img src="img_link" style="flex : 1;margin : 0 5%">
   <img src="img_link" style="flex : 1; margin : 0 5%">
   <img src="img_link" style="flex : 1; margin : 0 5%">
</div>
```